# Vertices stand out of object while animating!

Tags: animation, mesh, vertices, weight-painting, rigify

Hello blender community.
First, sry for my bad english, hope you understand it anyway.
Second, I have a problem animating my object.
Everytime I use the foot IK controller, my mesh deforms in a weird way.

[image: Weird spikes]

Or when I move the whole mesh

[image: And this one]

I already tried weight painting but that doesn't change anything.
Can someone help me please?

Comment: I already tried this, but it had no effect.